# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore: how to handle logout

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, identityserver4

I am using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore to apply swagger in our system and use ID4 to authenticate,... It works well. However, we cannot handle logout event to redirect to logout page. I follow it guideline to enable oauth2.

Could you please let me know how to setup to handle logout? Thanks

Comment: You can only log out from OAuth provider, but not from pages that pass around the token. Once a token is issued, it's valid until it expires or you keep track (i.e. using distributed memory cache such as redis) of tokens and revoke then, but this require to check this on every request which beats many of the benefits of oauth. Logout in OAuth/Token based processes equals to simply deleting the access and identity/refresh tokens

Comment: Thanks, I am using Identity Server 4 like oath provider. With our client app, we can logout and it works well. However, with swagger UI, it has just have "Logout" button and I dont know how to configure it.

Comment: It seems to be an issue still. See the GitHub issue https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/436